# how to put <a> tag at top right corner of card with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have card which has image in background

```
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-4">
    <div class="card">

      <img class="card-img" style=" filter: brightness(75%);" src="{{$category->photo}}">
      <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <a class="text-right"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
        <h1 class="card-title text-white text-center ">{{$category->name}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

There is pen icon which I want to put on top right corner

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the position utility classes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/position/

For example:

```
<div class="card position-relative">
  <!-- other elements -->
  <a class="text-right position-absolute top-0 end-0"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
</div>
```

Learn more about CSS position: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

you can also do use bootsrap's float-right class.

```
 <div class="position-relative">
     <a class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"position-absolute top-0 end-0 me-4 mt-5"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details about your code. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).